Retrieve Custom URL for the Experience Community in Apex: how can I do that?
Retrieve Custom URL for the Experience Community in Apex: how can I do that?
For example, I have site X and Domain Y and I need to know what is the Custom URL for the Site X using Domain Y?

This is easy, we need to query DomainSite standard object, for example, if Domain Y uses CdnPartner and Site name is X, we may use the following query to get this data
SELECT Id, Domain.Domain, PathPrefix, Site.Name FROM DomainSite WHERE Domain.HttpsOption = 'CdnPartner' AND Site.Name = 'Y'

and then we can just concatenate the Domain.Domain with PathPrefix to get the full link
